# HTML5 Canvas flip vertical function works in Firefox but not Chrome or Safari. why?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, getimagedata

Here is the code that works perfectly well in Firefox, but I just do not get why it does not work in Webkit browsers! Note: Im using jQuery to select the canvas element.

```
    (function()
    {
        flipV=function(imageData)
        {
            var n = new Array();
            var d = imageData.data;
        // loop through over row of pixels
            for (var row=0;row<imageData.height;row++)
            {
            // loop over every column
                for (var col=0;col<imageData.width;col++)
                {
                    var si,di,sp,dp;

                // source pixel
                    sp=(imageData.width*row)+col; 

                // destination pixel
                dp=(imageData.width*((imageData.height-1)-row))+col; 

                // source and destination indexes, will always reference the red pixel
                si=sp*4;
                    di=dp*4;

                    n[di]=d[si]; // red
                    n[di+1]=d[si+1]; // green
                    n[di+2]=d[si+2]; // blue
                    n[di+3]=d[si+3]; // alpha
                }
            }
            imageData.data=n;

            return imageData;
        };

        var imgs = ['/images/myimage.png'];

        var $c=$('#canvas');
        var cxt=$c[0].getContext('2d');


        var w=$c.width();
        var h=$c.height();

        var img1 = new Image();
        img1.onload=function()
        {   
            cxt.drawImage(img1,0,0,img1.width,img1.height,0,0,w,h);
            imageData = flipV(cxt.getImageData(0,0,w,h));
            cxt.putImageData(imageData,0,0)

        };
        img1.src=imgs[0];

    }
)();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Edit:** I played with this a little, and got it to work. The problem is when when you set `imageData.data = n`. It looks like Chrome/WebKit won't work with a different `data` array. To make it work, I passed the context object to `flipV` and called `createImageData(imageData.width, imageData.height)` to get a fresh ImageData object, set `n = newImageData.data`, and returned `newImageData`.

I'll leave the rest here for reference:

There is an easier and most likely faster way to flip an image though, that will work across domains. You can use the `scale` function to automatically flip everything anything you draw along the y axis. You just need to be sure to call `save()` and `restore()` and remember to adjust the location since everything is flipped.

```
function drawVFlipped(ctx, img) {
    ctx.save();
    // Multiply the y value by -1 to flip vertically
    ctx.scale(1, -1);
    // Start at (0, -height), which is now the bottom-left corner
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, -img.height);
    ctx.restore();
}
```

Comment: @Mathew Actually other filters I have that use getImageData(), such as grayscale or invert, work perfectly fine with local images. It seems to be just this one flipV filter that has a problem.

I had tried the negative scaling before but had problems with an "INDEX_SIZE_ERR". Just realized it's because I'm using drawImage to also crop the source and was placing the - on the wrong height var.

You are right that negative scaling is a much easier method than modifying imageData, tho I'd still like to know why my filter works in FF and not Webkit.

Comment: I had a feeling that that new array might have something to do with it. Thanks for experimenting and confirming! 

You are indeed correct that the negative scaling is a much better,easier,more elegant way of handling the flip, so I will just continue on with that method.